# How do I get an error or confirmation from mailutils to c++?

Tags: c++, linux, email, debian-jessie, ssmtp

I use a system() call to mailutils to send email alerts from a c++ program (running on a Debian Linux machine). Is there a way for my program to determine success or failure?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "success or failure"?

Comment: Let's say the internet was down and the mail did not send. How might my program know to keep trying?

Comment: That depends on what your mail client can return as an indicator - the system() library function returns the exit status of the program it executes, which you can test in your C++ code.

Comment: Ahhhh... I didn't know that. Will have to try, thanks!